# How can i make my plugins load assemblies from their own path, instead of my .exe loading them

Tags: c#

I have a small software application where i have some plugins in the form of .zip files i download to a folder called "plugins", this is my sample disc structure:

```
MyApplication.exe
  |
  |
  |-Plugins (Folder)
       |
       |- Plugin1 (Folder)
       |     |
       |     |- MyPluginAssembly1.dll
       |
       |- Plugin2 (Folder)
             |
             |- MyPluginAssembly1.dll
             |- Assembly1.dll
             |- Assembly2.dll
```

My problem is that i have this plugin (Plugin2) which has some assemblies it need to load. Problem is that it will not work if the assemblies are located in the plugins folder the .exe which is loading the plugin cannot load the assemblies unless they are registered or resides "beside" the .exe file. Right now i copy the assemblies (Assembly1, Assembly2) to the folder which contains the .exe assembly. Is there any way i can keep the files inside the plugin folder where they belong?

Comment: why not add the custom paths where your libs present to the PATH env variable? thought not a good solution, but can be a work around. Even bad could be to add in GAC.

Comment: Use LoadFrom(), not LoadFile() to load the plugin assembly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach to `AssemblyResolve` event and load your assemblies from any path you like.

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += (sndr, resolveEventArgs) =>
{
    return Assembly.LoadFile("......");
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location`.

Note that this doesn't *always* work - it will likely only produce the intended behaviour when the library is a physical .dll on disk. There are other ways to load assemblies in .NET - but by the looks of it your application will work fine.

Do note that I haven't tried it, so test it thoroughly with various deployment scenarios before using it (obviously!)

**edit #1:** I'm now doubting whether I've understood your question correctly. `GetExecutingAssembly` will return the current assembly (fairly obviously) so if you want the path of the plugin library, you'd need to call this method **in** the plugin library. Is this what you wanted, or are you asking how to get the paths(s) of the plugin(s) from the application executable?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use the codebase tag in the configuration file, like MSDN suggests [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2h3sywsc%28v=VS.71%29.aspx). Note you can only place libraries which are under you directory main application (like in your use case), unless you register them in the [GAC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yf1d93sz.aspx). Here are some useful tips on [CodeBase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4191fzwb%28v=VS.71%29.aspx).